# angular to display rows in the table if condition is met

Tags: angular, search, filter

I have table data getting from .json file by component.ts:

```
import lfirawdata from '../../../assets/json/data.json';
    interface lfiexport {
    
      id: string;
      sgm: string;
      pl: string;
      qr: string; 
}

export class lfiComponent implements OnInit{
  
  lfilist: lfiexport [] = lfirawdata;
```

Then, I use in component html to display it in table:

```
<tr *ngFor="let lfiexport of lfilist">
<td>{{lfiexport.id}}</td>
etc.
```

I want to add a selection menu on top of the table, once you select the value, table will show only those rows, which have this selected value.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Single City" name="city">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let sgm of sgms" [value]="sgm.value">
         {{ sgm.viewValue }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

I tried to do it with <tr *ngIf=lfiexport.sgm.includes('xxx')">, but it doesnt work.
Can anyone help with this simple solution?

Thanks

Comment: i believe the best solution for you is to ngFor over filteredList already

Answer (score 0):

What I think is Why don't you use change event of dropdown and repopulate yourr table according to seleceted value.

Comment: While this may he considered an answer or in support of an answer, not providing code may constitute this answer being better served as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

you must to use a additional array to content all the data. So at the start the array **data** and the array **lfilist** are the same. Then when you select some item in the dropdown you can do

```
this.lfilist = this.data.filter(i => your_condition_expression)
```

and the table will be updated

Hope this can help you.